# R programming : Error in Evaluate : Unused arguments

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, evaluation

I am new in R. 
I am using R language to build prototype for Recommendation System using `recommenderlab` package.
I am getting below error message.

```
Error in evaluate(x = eval_sets, method = models_to_evaluate, n = n_recommendations) : 
  unused arguments (x = eval_sets, method = models_to_evaluate, n = n_recommendations)
```

On executing below code :

```
library(recommenderlab)
library(ggplot2)
data("MovieLense")
ratings_movies <- MovieLense[rowCounts(MovieLense) > 27, colCounts(MovieLense) > 21]
n_fold <- 4
items_to_keep <- 15
rating_threshold <- 3
eval_sets <- evaluationScheme(data = ratings_movies,
                              method = "cross-validation",
                              k = n_fold,
                              given = items_to_keep,
                              goodRating = rating_threshold)

models_to_evaluate <- list(
  IBCF_cos = list(name = "IBCF", param = list(method = "cosine")),
  IBCF_cor = list(name = "IBCF", param = list(method = "pearson")),
  UBCF_cos = list(name = "UBCF", param = list(method = "cosine")),
  UBCF_cor = list(name = "UBCF", param = list(method = "pearson")),
  random = list(name = "RANDOM", param=NULL)
)

n_recommendations <- c(1, 5, seq(10, 100, 10))

list_results <- evaluate(x = eval_sets,
                    method = models_to_evaluate,
                    n = n_recommendations)
```

I am not sure why the error is coming and how can I fix this.

I will be very thankful if somebody can help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is working fine on my system.. is there another method called evaluate in your environment?

Comment: Try: `recommenderlab::evaluate(x = eval_sets, method = models_to_evaluate, n = n_recommendations)`

Comment: @Coatless : Thanks a lot to. Code worked for me.

Comment: It would be great and very helpful, if you can also share links for good R tutorials. So, I will learn and not make these silly mistakes in future.

Comment: Feel free to search the internet using any of the search engine. Plenty of information out there. I hope @Coatless answers this in a proper answer and explains why his approach works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for why `evaluate()` is having difficult being called is R believe a function exists without the arguments you are specifying. This evaluate function lacks even a `...` so the additional arguments are not referring to any kind of fixed or unfixed parameters and, hence, are "unused" arguments. The underlying reason for this is either

1. The `recommenderlab` package is not loaded via `library()`/`require()`, or
2. Another R package is present that uses the name `evaluate()` as one of the functions.

Hence, we opt to simplify the confusion R has when it searches through the different package namespaces for `evaluate()` by specifying the package namespace that should be used, e.g. `recommenderlab::`

Thus, the reason for:

```
recommenderlab::evaluate(x = eval_sets, method = models_to_evaluate, n = n_recommendations)
```